How to pass a MutableList from a ViewModel to the MainActivity
I have a quite simple app for creating, let's say, incidents. The user can add, edit and delete them. They are stored in a Back4App backend. I used some example found in the Internet, edited it to meet my needs and it was quite ok. Everything was working. However, the list was implemented as a dictionary, which I later changed to MutableList. After that the mainactivity won't show the incident list any more. Adding a new incident is still possible and it is stored correctly, but nothing is shown on the list. I've debugged and the data fetch is working, but passing the list to the mainactivity seems not to work.
Im out of ideas and competence (if there were any in the first place). I guess the problem is somewhere in the MainActivity.kt or/and AppViewModel.kt files, I'll post both here. I don't know the essential parts, so whole files here.
class AppViewModel : ViewModel() {
    val CallForHelps: MutableList<CallForHelp> = mutableListOf()

    init {
        val query = com.parse.ParseQuery.getQuery<com.parse.ParseObject>("CallForHelp")
        query.orderByDescending("createdAt")
        query.findInBackground { cfhs, e ->
            if (e == null) {
                for (parseCFH in cfhs) {
                    val cfh = CallForHelp(
                        objectId = parseCFH.objectId,
                        title = parseCFH.getString("Title")!!,
                        description = parseCFH.getString("Description")!!,
                        status = parseCFH.getString("Status")!!,
                        createdAt = parseCFH.createdAt,
                        loca = null,
                    )
                    this.CallForHelps.plus(cfh)
                }
            } else {
                println("Error: ${e.message}")
            }
        }
    }

    companion object {
        @Volatile
        private var instance: AppViewModel? = null

        fun getInstance(): AppViewModel {
            return instance ?: synchronized(this) {
                instance ?: AppViewModel().also { instance = it }
            }
        }
    }
}

And
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    private val viewM = AppViewModel.getInstance()

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        val context = this as Context

        setContent {
            MainActivityContent(
                viewModel = viewM,
                onCfhListItemClick = {
                    val intent = Intent(context, FormActivity::class.java)
                    intent.putExtra("index", viewM.CallForHelps.indexOf(it))
                    context.startActivity(intent)
                },
                onAddClick = {
                    val intent = Intent(context, FormActivity::class.java)
                    intent.putExtra("index", 0)
                    context.startActivity(intent)
                },
            )
        }
    }
}

@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
fun MainActivityContent(
    viewModel: AppViewModel,
    onCfhListItemClick: (cfh: CallForHelp) -> Unit,
    onAddClick: () -> Unit,
) {
    val cfhs = viewModel.CallForHelps
    MaterialTheme {
        Scaffold(
            topBar = { TopAppBar(title = { Text("Help requests") }) },
            floatingActionButton = {
                ExtendedFloatingActionButton(
                    onClick = { onAddClick() },
                    icon = { Icon(Icons.Filled.Add, contentDescription = "Add") },
                    text = { Text("Add") },
                )
            },
        ) { contentPadding ->
            Box(modifier = Modifier.padding(contentPadding)) {
                NoteList(cfhs, onCfhListItemClick = { onCfhListItemClick(it) })
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun CfhListItem(cfh: CallForHelp, onCfhListItemClick: (cfh: CallForHelp) -> Unit) {
    Row(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .clickable(onClick = { onCfhListItemClick(cfh) })
            .padding(16.dp),
        verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically,
    ) {
        val imageModifier = Modifier
            .size(50.dp)

        when (cfh.status) {
            "Open" ->
                Image(
                    painterResource(R.drawable.open),
                    contentDescription = stringResource(id = R.string.open_description),
                    modifier = imageModifier,
                )

            "Ongoing" ->
                Image(
                    painter = painterResource(R.drawable.ongoing),
                    contentDescription = stringResource(id = R.string.ongoing_description),
                    modifier = imageModifier,
                )

            "Closed" ->
                Image(
                    painter = painterResource(R.drawable.closed),
                    contentDescription = stringResource(id = R.string.closed_description),
                    modifier = imageModifier,
                )
        }

        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.width(8.dp))
        Column {
            Text(text = cfh.title, fontSize = 18.sp)
            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(4.dp))
            Text(
                text = SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.YYYY HH:mm").format(cfh.createdAt),
                fontSize = 14.sp,
                maxLines = 1,
                overflow = TextOverflow.Ellipsis,
            )
            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(4.dp))
            Text(
                text = cfh.description,
                fontSize = 14.sp,
                maxLines = 1,
                overflow = TextOverflow.Ellipsis,
            )
            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(4.dp))
            Text(
                text = "Link placeholder",
                fontSize = 14.sp,
                maxLines = 1,
                overflow = TextOverflow.Ellipsis,
            )
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun NoteList(cfhs: MutableList<CallForHelp>, onCfhListItemClick: (cfh: CallForHelp) -> Unit) {
    LazyColumn {
        items(cfhs) { cfh ->
            CfhListItem(cfh, onCfhListItemClick = onCfhListItemClick)
        }
    }
}


A MutableList cannot be observed by Compose. Everything that changes in your view model and that the UI should react to should be exposed as a Flow: https://developer.android.com/kotlin/flow/stateflow-and-sharedflow#stateflow

Also please don't use !!, it will crash your app. If you want to know more why you shouldn't ignore Kotlin's null-safety, I just recently wrote another answer on this topic: https://stackoverflow.com/a/78341453/6216216

Ok, that's far beyond my knowledge. I'll use the dictionary style.

Well, that's the state-of-the-art way to develop Android apps. Especially with Compose it will be hard to avoid flows.
